# Shortest uncommon prefix from a set of strings

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a string A and a set of string S. Need to find an optimum method to find a prefix of A which is not a prefix of any of the strings in S.

Example

A={apple}

S={april,apprehend,apprehension}

Output should be "appl" and not "app" since "app" is prefix of both "apple" and "apprehension" but "appl" is not.

I know the trie approach; by making a trie of set S and then traversing in the trie for string A.

But what I want to ask is can we do it without trie?

Like can we compare every pair (A,Si), Si = ith string from set S and get the largest common prefix out of them.In this case that would be "app" , so now the required ans would be "appl".

This would take 2 loops(one for iterating through S and another for comparing Si and A).

Can we improve upon this??

Please suggest an optimum approach.

Comment: Do you consider a string comparaison as a loop ?

Comment: @Matt If A={apple} and S1 ={april} have to be compared then I have to use a loop that would terminate after "ap" because the 3rd characters p and r are not same.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your question, you ask for an optimum approach which has been given to you but you want to do without it

Comment: Using a trie is probably the best approach. Why would you not want to use that? What even makes you think there's a fundamentally different approach with similar performance?

Comment: @Matt I am having difficulty in traversing a trie. I have made a trie with Strings in S , but traversing A in this trie is what's the problem for me. Can you instead tell me how to traverse a trie? I think it may be possible through DFS but I am not sure.

Comment: @AyushGoyal So ask a new question about the implementation of a trie in your language, after some searches of course

Comment: @AyushGoyal You start at the root and just go to the child corresponding to the next letter in A. It's kind of like DFS, but you're not searching, you're just going directly to the correct child repeatedly. You should be able to find plenty of implementations of that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you had in mind, but here's one way to do it:

- Keep a variable `longest`, initialised to `0`.
- Loop over all elements `S[i]` of S,
  setting `longest = max(longest, matchingPrefixLength(S[i], A))`.
- Return the prefix from `A` of length `longest+1`.

This uses `O(1)` space and takes `O(length(S)*average length of S[i])` time.

This is optimal (at least for the worst case) since you can't get around needing to look at every character of every element in `S`.

Example:

```
A={apple}
S={april,apprehend,apprehension}

longest = 0

The longest prefix for S[0] and A is 2
So longest = max(0,2) = 2

The longest prefix for S[1] and A is 3
So longest = max(2,3) = 3

The longest prefix for S[2] and A is 3
So longest = max(3,3) = 3

Now we return the prefix of length longest+1 = 4, i.e. "appl"
```

---

Note that there are actually 2 trie-based approaches:

- Store only `A` in the trie. Iterate through the trie for each element from `S` to eliminate prefixes.

  This uses much less memory than the second approach (but still more than the approach above). At least assuming `A` isn't much, much longer than `S[i]`, but you can optimise to stop at the longest element in `S` or construct the tree as we go to avoid this case.
- Store all elements from `S` in the trie. Iterate through the trie with `A` to find the shortest non-matching prefix.

  This approach is significantly faster if you have lots of `A`'s that you want to query for a constant set `S` (since you only have to set up the trie once, and do a single lookup for each `A`, where-as you have to create a new trie and run through each `S[i]` for each `A` for the first approach).

Answer (score 0):

What is your input size?

Let's model your input as being of N+1 strings whose lengths are about M characters. Your total input size is about M(N+1) character, plus some proportional amount of apparatus to encode that data in a usable format (data structure overhead).

Your algorithm ...

```
maxlen = 0
for i = 1 to N
    for j = 1 to M
        if A[j] = S[i][j] then
            if j > maxlen then maxlen = j
            break
print A[1...maxlen]
```

... performs up M x N iterations of the innermost loop, reading two characters each time, for a total of 2MN characters read.

Recall our input data size was about M(N+1) also. So our question now is whether we can solve this problem, in the worst case, looking at asymptotically less than the total input (you do a little less than looking at all the input twice, or linear in the input size). The answer is no. Consider this worst case:

- length of A is M'
- length of all strings in S is M'
- A differs from N-1 strings in S by the last two characters
- A differs from 1 string in S by only the last character

Any algorithm must look at M'-1 characters of N-1 strings, plus M' characters of 1 string, to correctly determine the answer of this problem instance is A.

```
(M'-1)(N'-1) + N = M'N - M' - N + 1 + N = M'N - M' + 1
```

For N >= 2, the dominant terms in both M'(N+1) and M'N' are both M'N, meaning that for N >= 2, both the input size *and* the amount of that input any correct algorithm must read is O(MN). Your algorithm is O(MN). Any other algorithm cannot be asymptotically better.